# NO_WRAP cannot be resolved or is not a field?

Tags: android

I'm trying use Base64 to make a Http Authentication but when I insert Base64.NO_WRAP does return: `NO_WRAP cannot be resolved or is not a field`. I have Base64 in my packages.

I'm trying this.

```
public static String getBasicAuthentication(){
    String auth = new String(Base64.encode((USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD).getBytes(),Base64.URL_SAFE|Base64.NO_WRAP));
    return auth;        
}
```

how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem

`import android.util.Base64;`